# span display block makes text after the span drop as well

Tags: css

HTML:

```
<p>
<a href="#">my 
<span>favorites</span>
</a>
(13)
</p>
```

I want "favorites" to drop after "my", and then to **separately style** "(13)", which should be on **the same line** as "favorites".

I tried with the above markup and the following CSS but (13) also drops:

```
p span a { display: block; }
```

(13) should stay on the same line as "favorites" so it looks like

```
my
favorites(13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
<a href="#">my<br>favorites<span>(13)</span></a>
```

**The longer version (more flexibility)**

If you don't want a line break, you could use a block element. Now, since block elements aren't allowed inside inline elements (`<a>`), you should use span tags and style them as block elements.

```
<a href="#">
    my
    <span class="second-line">
        favorites <span class="count">(13)</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

And the CSS:

```
a .second-line {
    display: block;
}
a .count {
    color: #888888;
}
```

Comment: nice one. that works fine. I will accept this answer as soon as I am allowed (11 mins)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<p>
<a href="#">my 
<p>favorites <span>(13)</span></p>
</a>

</p>
```